# Connecting Raspberry Pi 3 to the internet

Tags: pi-3, wifi

I am planning to connect raspberry pi 3 to a simple electronic equipment. The pi would run an application collecting some data from the equipment. I would now like to send this data over the internet, say send it to a specified email. This can be ofcourse achieved by connecting the pi to a router (wifi/ ethernet).

However considering I do not have any existing router/access point connection, how can I connect the pi to the internet ? Is using the pi wifi dongle with pi 3 the only option?

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand the question.  To make an Internet connection, you will need either an Ethernet connection or a WiFi access point that does have an Internet connection.  When you get your connection, you will have some serious security concerns.  Do a search on "hardening Raspberry Pi."

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to buy additional hardware, there are some options for putting GSM (and possibly other) cellular transmit/receive modules onto your device.  That would allow you to send at least some data (not sure about the level of performance) without WiFi or Ethernet, assuming that you have cellular reception at your location.

You can easily find such product via Internet search. I don't have specific experience with any particular version.